# On-topic? Does Unicode have a symbol for synchronization (2 arrows following each other in a circle)?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

> I want to know whether Unicode has a symbol for synchronization, which
> is usually two arrows following each other in a circle.   These
> symbols ↷⎋⇄⟲☯♻ are the closest I could find.

I am afraid the question will be closed per [Let's play the guessing game](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/), even though I believe it would be searchable, and thus useful to many other people.

So, on-topic, off-topic, better on another site, or a plainly bad question?

At least apparently there was a time when this was deemed a good question on StackOverflow:
[Is there a Unicode glyph that looks like a "key" icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384380/is-there-a-unicode-glyph-that-looks-like-a-key-icon)

Comment: offtopic for where? [so]? definitely.

Comment: @Sathya, nothing to do whatsoever with programming...

Comment: @vonbrand yeah, I meant off-topic; not on-topic. *I need coffee*

Comment: @Sathya, enjoy your coffee.

Comment: For the record, the question you link to is definitely also off-topic. It's probably only still open since no-one's called attention to it until now.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely not on topic at Stack Overflow. It is simply not a programming problem.

With a bit of work, I can imagine that it might be possible that it could be suitable at [UX.SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com) or at [Graphic Design.SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)* (I've qualified that statement repeatedly because I'm not a member on either of those sites and don't *actually* know whether it would be on topic there.) You probably want to check in first with a Meta question similar to this one on the appropriate per-site Meta.

Before doing so, however, I suggest that you would need to turn it into something other than just "look through the Unicode tables for me". If you were to elaborate on your requirements -- why it is you're interested in a Unicode symbol (and limitations on alternatives), restrictions on the actual form, what exactly you're using it for, and so on -- you would be more likely to have a question which would elicit thoughtful but factual answers from experts.

---

*Based on a question in a related vein there: [What is the name of this heart-like decorative symbol?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16196/what-is-the-name-of-this-heart-like-decorative-symbol)